# How to add Spark Dstream elements into ArrayBuffer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to add dstream elements to ArrayBuffer for further processes.But it dosen't work.

```
var newBatchMeter = new ArrayBuffer[String]()

newBatchReadingDstream.foreachRDD( rdd => {
  for(item <- rdd.collect()) {
    newBatchMeter += item.ID
  }
})

newBatchMeter.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that the foreach clause is executed in the worker and your array buffer is declared on the driver. 
Collecting a `DStream` wouldn't work since it's an infinite stream, you could persist the data to files and later load them into an ArrayBuffer.

I would thing the best approach would be to find a way to do the the processing you wanted to do with the ArrayBuffer using the `DStream` primitives

something like:

```
newBatchReadingDstream.map(item => item.ID)
```